# How can I implement turn to turn directions for indoor navigation in xamarin.Android?

Tags: navigation, xamarin.android

How can I get the list of directions for navigation from a point A to B knowing the coordinates of each point and each node of the path and without displaying any map?

I use geomagnetic localisation based on earth's magnetic field.